# Retrieve all currently installed software on Windows 7,8, and 10

Tags: java, windows, powershell, windows-10

I basically need to retrieve the `name`, `version`, and `install_date` of  *all* currently installed software in Windows (7,8,10).

I've found this:

```java
String command = "powershell.exe Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | ConvertTo-Json";

Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

But it's not really working.

**Edit:**

Whenever I run the command, it tells me that

> 'DisplayName' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: But it is kinda working?

Comment: I've tried. I've edited the question to include the output.

Comment: It looks like Windows is interpreting the "|" as a pipe.  Does that make sense in this context?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I barely use windows, I just have to implement this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only it were that easy........

```
String command = "powershell.exe Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | ConvertTo-Json";
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I don't know where you found that snippet of code but unfortunately it doesn't quite work that way as you've already found out. The reason you are getting the error:

```
'DisplayName' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

is because the PowerShell command string you are trying to run needs to be applied to a **PowerShell Command Prompt** not the *Windows Command Prompt* the way you are doing it. To do that you need to start PowerShell first typing **PowerShell** then hitting the ENTER key. The window looks the same but you'll always know when you're working with a PowerShell Prompt when there is a whitespace between the prompt and the blinking caret and of course PowerShell is indicated within the Command Prompt Window Title Bar: `Command Prompt - PowerShell`. To exit the PowerShell Prompt simply type **exit** then hit the ENTER key. Notice the title bar now?

There is another way however and that is to use PowerShell's **-Command** command and enclose your command string in quotation marks but before we get into that you need to know that your command string is slightly flawed...you're missing a specific argument, the **Select-Object** argument and this would go just before the **DisplayName** property name:

```
          Here
      ┌─────┴─────┐
... | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | ConvertTo-Json
```

You need this argument for your specific Command String to work, after all, you are selecting specific objects.

PowerShell help specifies that the **-Command** command:

> executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they
>   were typed at the PowerShell Command Prompt, and then it exits, unless
>   **NoExit** is specified. The value of Command can be "-", a string, or a script block.
>
> If the value of Command is "-", the command text is read from standard
>   input.
>
> If the value of Command is a script block, the script block must be
>   enclosed in braces ({}). You can specify a script block only when
>   running PowerShell.exe in Windows PowerShell. The results of the
>   script block are returned to the parent shell as deserialized XML
>   objects, not live objects.
>
> If the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last
>   parameter in the command , because any characters typed after the
>   command are interpreted as the command arguments.
>
> To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the
>   format: "& {}" where the quotation marks indicate a string
>   and the invoke operator (&) causes the command to be executed.

Well, this obviously puts a little light on the subject. So there are two ways you can accomplish this, enclose your command string in quotation marks or make the command string a invoked Command String Block:

**In Quotation Marks:**

```
String command = "PowerShell.exe -Command \"Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | ConvertTo-Json\"";
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

**In A PowerShell Invoke Command String Block:**

```
String command = "PowerShell.exe -Command \"& {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | ConvertTo-Json}\"";
Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Hmmmmm...Now it is that easy.

Below is a method that can help take the hassle out of things. It automatically invokes PowerShell so all you need to supply is your command string without the "powershell.exe" in it.

```
/**
 * Most PowerShell commands need to be run through a PowerShell Command
 * Window (unless the -Command is used) which means that PowerShell needs 
 * to be run first before the command can be used otherwise you end up 
 * receiving an error something like:<pre>
 *
 *    'CommandName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 *    operable program or batch file.</pre><br>
 * <p>
 * This method solves that problem. Here you don't supply the "PowerShell"
 * substring as the start of your Command String but instead you merely supply
 * the Command String you would supply to PowerShell. As an example, suppose
 * you want to collect the list of files and folders contained within the
 * currently focused drive and directory within the local file system:
 * <pre>
 *      {@code
 *          String command = "ls";   // A PowerShell command
 *          List<String> list = runPowerShellCommand(command);
 *
 *          for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 *              System.out.println(list.get(i));
 *          }
 *      }</pre>
 * <p>
 * Your console window will display a list of files and folders.<br><br>
 *
 * @param commandString (String) The command string to run through
 *                      PowerShell.<br>
 *
 * @param options       (Optional - Two Of, Boolean):<pre>
 *      trimLines       - (Boolean - Default is true) By default lines returned
 *                        from the PowerShell process are added to a List Interface
 *                        object with all lines trimmed. If you don't want this
 *                        then supply false to this optional parameter. If you are
 *                        retrieving data from PowerShell in a specific format like
 *                        Json then you definitely want to pass boolean false to
 *                        this parameter.
 *
 *                        If an argument is passed to the optional skipBlankLines
 *                        parameter then you MUST pass an argument to this optional
 *                        parameter as well.
 *
 *      skipBlankLines  - (Boolean - Default is true) By default blank lines returned
 *                        from the PowerShell process are skipped and not added to the
 *                        List Interface object that will be returned. If you don't want
 *                        this then supply false to this optional parameter. If you are
 *                        retrieving data from PowerShell in a specific format like
 *                        Json then you definitely want to pass boolean false to
 *                        this parameter.
 *
 *                        If an argument is passed to this optional parameter then
 *                        you MUST pass an argument to the trimLines optional parameter
 *                        as well.</pre>
 *
 * @return (List Interface of String ({@code List<String>})) PowerShell
 *         output data.<br>
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public List<String> runPowerShellCommand(String commandString, boolean... options) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean trimLines = true;       // Default
    boolean skipBlankLines = true;  // Default
    // Setup optional parameters if supplied.
    if (options.length > 0) {
      trimLines = options[0];
      if (options.length >= 2) {
         skipBlankLines = options[1];
      }

    }

    // Fire up PowerShell and run the supplied command string through it.
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String cmds[] = {"powershell", commandString};
    Process proc = runtime.exec(cmds);
    // Try With resources used here.
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (trimLines) {
                line = line.trim();
            }
            if (skipBlankLines) {
                if (line.trim().equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            list.add(line); // Add line from input stream to list.
        }
    }
    proc.destroy(); // Kill the process
    return list;    // return the goods if any
}
```

And here is how you might use it with your specific Command String:

```
String command = "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\"
               + "Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName, "
               + "DisplayVersion, InstallDate | ConvertTo-Json";

List<String> list;
try {
    list = runPowerShellCommand(command, false, false);
    // Display the list in console...
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

This will display your registry data query within the Console Window.

As a side note, there are actually three places within the Windows Registry that can hold specifically installed applications and you might consider poling all of them and ignore duplicates:

- The list of programs that user sees in the section **Programs and
  Features** of the Control Panel is built on the base of the contents
  of the registry key:

  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**

  The registry key above contains only programs installed **“for all
  users”** of Windows.
- For 32-bit applications on a 64-bit operating system you would
  need to additionally get the contents of registry branch:

  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**
- If an application was installed in the **“for this user”** mode, then
  it should be present in the registry key:

  **HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**

Accordingly, to get a **complete** list of installed software, you will need to pole information from all three branches of the Windows Registry.

Comment: this works nicely. If the only command I needed to execute was the one I provided, I assume I don't need the trimLines and skipBlankLines booleans?

Comment: No..you wouldn't just as the sample code above demonstrates, see the line: `list = runPowerShellCommand(command, false, false);`.

Comment: yeah i'll just be removing those. nice doc btw. thanks!